# Clicking 'back' on Android action bar exits app

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to incorporate the 'back' button in the action bar. On initializing the first activity and clicking on to the second activity, it all works well. But on clicking the 'back' button on the action bar, the app, without errors, exits the app instead of going back to the main/parent activity.

How do I get it to go back to the main/parent activity?

```
   SecondActivity.java
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_SecondActivity);

        ///as part of back action on action bar, not sure if it works
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if          it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.SecondActivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

      @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
             ///replaced NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); 
                       finish();
                return true;
            }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```

}

in the manifest file,

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.backbuttontry"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
    android:debuggable="true"  >



     <activity
        android:name="com.example.backbuttontry.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity

      android:name="com.example.backbuttontry.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       android:parentActivityName="com.example.backbuttontry.MainActivity" >

       <meta-data

      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"

      android:value="com.example.backbuttontry.MainActivity" />
     </activity>

      </application>

      </manifest>
```

I am new to android and am trying out new things. Will appreciate any advice/help I can get. Thanks.

The logcat as below doesn't say much

```
    04-10 00:23:38.444: W/EGL_emulation(704): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    04-10 00:23:40.953: W/EGL_emulation(704): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, your_class.class);
        if(NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)){
            TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
                    .addNextIntent(upIntent)
                    .startActivities();
            finish();
```

Instead of this

```
 NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

EDIT:

Even easier solution, just finish the activity like shown below.

change the following. FROM THIS

```
            case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
```

TO THIS

```
            case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
```

Comment: I've replaced the lines of code as you asked and imported intent etc.. but Eclipse says there is a problem with 'from' in line 3, 'TaskStackBuilder.from(this). ...'The method from(Rl) is undefined for the type TaskStackBuilder'

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html...Check this link.

Comment: Tried as you suggested replacing "NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);" with "finish();" but the same thing happens. Its exits from the second activity whether I click on the 'back' in the action bar OR the physical back button. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: I understand if clicking on the action bar 'back' button doesn't work, but how come even on the physical back button it exits the app?

Comment: I guess you're running this app in emulator!!. May be app is doing too much work and that's why its stopping the activity. just a guess. I would just create another project, and try implementing the same.

Answer (score 0):

just declare this code within Activity tag in Android Manifest file.

for ex:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the same thing is reoccuring. It exits app without errors on clicking the '<' button in the action bar. I've posted the logcat above..